# Avogadro Conformer Properties with Linux Version

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

My Windows version of Avogadro has the following menu point:

```
View > Properties > Conformer Properties
```

[image: Conformer Properties of Avogadro]

My vanilla Avogadro version under Ubuntu does not even have the menu. What do I need to do, to either activate the menu or to get to this option under Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem.

[image: Avogadro on Linux]
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and installed Avogadro from the repository. The version is 1.1.1, just as described on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/avogadro).

This version does have the menu entry in question:
`Ansicht > Eigenschaften > Konformereneigenschaften`

After a conformation search, it does open a table with the found conformers and their energies.